# No route matches [POST] "/registrations/user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the devise gem, and I have had user registration working in the past. However, something seems to have broken.

```
Mavens::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :events
  resources :periods
  resources :products
  resources :cart_rows
  resources :product_requests
  resources :inqueries
   match '/profile',  to: 'static_pages#profile'

  # resources :registrations do
  #   member do
  #     post :save_period
  #   end
  # end

  root :to => 'static_pages#home'

  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/about"
end
```

I should have used a different name than "registrations" but this registration is for an event, not a user. I've commented that out thinking it had something to do with this breaking.

Here is my rake routes:

```
   new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)        devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)       devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)            devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)              devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                     devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)             devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                     devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                     devise/registrations#destroy
                  events GET    /events(.:format)                    events#index
                         POST   /events(.:format)                    events#create
               new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                events#new
              edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)           events#edit
                   event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                events#show
                         PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                events#update
                         DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                events#destroy
                 periods GET    /periods(.:format)                   periods#index
                         POST   /periods(.:format)                   periods#create
              new_period GET    /periods/new(.:format)               periods#new
             edit_period GET    /periods/:id/edit(.:format)          periods#edit
                  period GET    /periods/:id(.:format)               periods#show
                         PUT    /periods/:id(.:format)               periods#update
                         DELETE /periods/:id(.:format)               periods#destroy
                products GET    /products(.:format)                  products#index
                         POST   /products(.:format)                  products#create
             new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)              products#new
            edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)         products#edit
                 product GET    /products/:id(.:format)              products#show
                         PUT    /products/:id(.:format)              products#update
                         DELETE /products/:id(.:format)              products#destroy
               cart_rows GET    /cart_rows(.:format)                 cart_rows#index
                         POST   /cart_rows(.:format)                 cart_rows#create
            new_cart_row GET    /cart_rows/new(.:format)             cart_rows#new
           edit_cart_row GET    /cart_rows/:id/edit(.:format)        cart_rows#edit
                cart_row GET    /cart_rows/:id(.:format)             cart_rows#show
                         PUT    /cart_rows/:id(.:format)             cart_rows#update
                         DELETE /cart_rows/:id(.:format)             cart_rows#destroy
        product_requests GET    /product_requests(.:format)          product_requests#index
                         POST   /product_requests(.:format)          product_requests#create
     new_product_request GET    /product_requests/new(.:format)      product_requests#new
    edit_product_request GET    /product_requests/:id/edit(.:format) product_requests#edit
         product_request GET    /product_requests/:id(.:format)      product_requests#show
                         PUT    /product_requests/:id(.:format)      product_requests#update
                         DELETE /product_requests/:id(.:format)      product_requests#destroy
               inqueries GET    /inqueries(.:format)                 inqueries#index
                         POST   /inqueries(.:format)                 inqueries#create
             new_inquery GET    /inqueries/new(.:format)             inqueries#new
            edit_inquery GET    /inqueries/:id/edit(.:format)        inqueries#edit
                 inquery GET    /inqueries/:id(.:format)             inqueries#show
                         PUT    /inqueries/:id(.:format)             inqueries#update
                         DELETE /inqueries/:id(.:format)             inqueries#destroy
                 profile        /profile(.:format)                   static_pages#profile
                    root        /                                    static_pages#home
       static_pages_home GET    /static_pages/home(.:format)         static_pages#home
      static_pages_about GET    /static_pages/about(.:format)        static_pages#about
```

And here is the view page:

```
<h2>Sign Up</h2> 
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) %> | <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
  <br />

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name%>

  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name%>

  <%= f.label :license_number %>
  <%= f.text_field :license_number %>

  <%= f.label :state %>
  <%= f.select :state, User::STATES%>

  <%= f.label :specialty %>
  <%= f.select :specialty, User::SPECIALTY%>



  <br />

  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas on what could have changed to break the routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `rails d` on the model and controller and that seemed to get it working. Pro_tip, always prefix variable names with something so they don't compete with names of other systems you pull in!